# Bash alias defined in script not working within the script

Tags: bash, scripting, alias

I found a weird thing:

When I do in the console,

```
alias a='echo aaa'
a
```

I get the output `aaa` as expected. But when I do a script, let's name it `script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
alias a='echo aaa'
a
```

and run it by doing `bash script.sh`, I get `script.sh: line 2: a: command not found`

How is this possible and how can I fix it?

Comment: Just try to change a alias to a simple variable, like this:

Comment: #!/bin/bash
alias a='echo aaa'
a